# Android home screen launcher

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher

First of all let me tell you guys that I am completely newbie to Android app development. 
I want to know how to launch home screen and then application home screen. 
i.e whenever you click on some app, first it will show some logo screen and then automatically jump to home screen of the app. 
I have my home screen of the app running, I just want to add some kind of logo screen when user click on the app.

I did little bit research on this and I found out

```
<intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

If I add this to logo activity then how to call app_home_screen activity automatically 
Hope I am clear enough to explain the question.

Comment: You mean like a [Splash screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen)?

Comment: I looked for the splash screen and yes I want that functionality only.
Thanks for the term , Let me google on that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

- Add a new Activity `SplashActivity` which will be the start Activity of your app.
- When your app starts, launch your `SplashActivity` and wait for some time.
- When you finish waiting, start your `MainActivity` and finish the `SplashActivity`.

Here is a good example:

**SplashScreenActivity:**

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout); //You need to define it in your layouts
    final int welcomeScreenDisplay = 3000; //splash lasts for 3 sec. You can change it
    /** create a thread to show splash up to splash time */
    Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {
        int wait = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                super.run();
                while (wait < welcomeScreenDisplay) {
                     sleep(100);
                     wait += 100;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
            } finally {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainScreenActivity.class));
                finish();
            }}
        };
        welcomeThread.start();

    }
}
```

And don't forget to add the activities to your Manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".MainScreenActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Comment: why cant i use SLEEP method instead of creating welcomeThread ? Hope I can use SLEEP in Android.
Any particular reason for implementing this way ?

Answer (score 2):

Although the other answers certainly work, here is an alternative to avoid having a separate activity just for your logo:

1. Place your ImageView as you would like (i.e. covering your full screen) before the other elements in your main activity layout (they will have an initial layout outside of the screen).
2. After calling setContentView in onCreate, run SystemClock.sleep(LOGO_TIME), where LOGO_TIME is an integer representing the number of milliseconds you want your logo to appear.
3. Finally, call setVisibility(View.GONE).

Your ImageView will be gone, and the other layout elements will fall into its place.

Answer (score 1):

One solution you could attempt is to load the logo as your main activity, and have the application pause for a few seconds before calling the 2nd activity, your 'true' home page.

To start that 2nd activity you'll use 'Intent' such as

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(myFirstActivity.this, realHomePage.class);
myFirstActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Just make sure to extend the Activity class in your home page class

Answer (score 0):

Have the main activity that gets called when your app icon is clicked on be an activity which has a view with only your logo on it. Something simple, just a RelativeLayout and an ImageView. After a time delay, have this activity start your actual main activity with an intent.

Comment: I tried this, used SystemClock.sleep(TIME) but in this case also Logo screen is coming after TIME seconds even though I setcontentView before sleep. ? Do you know the reason. I guess setcontentview will execute just before the exit of the method ?